# Proof of orthogonality using tensor notation

Tags: vectors, solution-verification, cross-product

Suppose $\textbf{A}$ is radial. Prove that $\operatorname{rot}\textbf{A}$ is a vector orthogonal to $\textbf{A}$. First show that $\varepsilon_{ijk}k_jk_k=0$.

I have no problem showing the second part but I don't know how to use it in the proof.
I want to prove the orthogonality with scalar product so I should obtain 0 from the equation. So far I have:
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\textbf{A}\ \cdot \ \textbf{A} = \hat{e_i}a_i(\varepsilon_{jkl}\hat{e_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}a_l)=\delta_{ij}\varepsilon_{jkl}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}a_la_i$$
I don't know what to do after this so that I use the shown property.

Comment: This is false in general, e.g. take $A=x_2\hat{e}_1+x_3\hat{e}_2+x_1\hat{e}_3$. Perhaps you're meant to add another assumption, e.g. that $A_i$ is a function of $x_i$ alone... although that would prove something even stronger, $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0}$. How about $\mathbf{A}$ being radial?

Comment: The only assumption in the exercise is that $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$ is in constant direction. I don't know if this is crucial to the problem.

Comment: Always mention every assumption! I've edited your question to include it.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll remember that. I didn't even know what radial means... We have yet to cover that druing the lectures but it's already on the list of problems. Classic, I guess. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: Radial means parallel to $\sum_ix_i\hat{e}_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $A_i=fx_i$ so$$A_j\varepsilon_{jkl}\partial_kA_l=fx_j\varepsilon_{jkl}\partial_k(fx_l)=f\underbrace{x_jx_l\varepsilon_{jkl}}_{0}\partial_kf+f^2x_j\underbrace{\varepsilon_{jkl}\partial_kx_l}_{\varepsilon_{jkl}\delta_{kl}=0}.$$